# Haskell checking nested data

Tags: haskell, recursion, nested, pattern-matching

I am new to Haskell and I have to be able to check if a regular expression contains Empty. Some of the conditions I have already defined, but I don't know to do it if the regular expression is nested as in the example 'test' below. If I run 'isEmpty test' it will return False since it's neither of the above defined cases as True. But since it contains the 'Star' statement it should contain 'Empty' as well.
I assume there will need to be some recursive checking of the expression but as of right now I don't know how to go about that.
I'd appreciate any help.

```
data RegExpr = Empty | Symbol Char | Star RegExpr | And RegExpr RegExpr | Or RegExpr RegExpr

isEmpty (Empty) = True
isEmpty (Star Empty) = True
isEmpty (Or _ Empty) = True
isEmpty (Or Empty _) = True
isEmpty (And Empty Empty) = True
isEmpty _ = False

test = Or (Symbol 'a') (Star (And (Symbol 'a') (Symbol 'a')))
```

Comment: What do you mean by “check”? Please give a clear explanation and several example inputs together with the desired results, and also explain what you've tried yourself already.

Comment: What about recursion in Haskell are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

You're exactly right: this problem should be solved recursively.  In fact, you should be able to write `isEmpty` using one line per constructor (so 5 lines, for each of `Empty`, `Symbol`, `Star`, `And`, and `Or`), with recursive calls generally used every place that a `RegExpr` appears in the definition of the constructor.  So, the line that handles `Symbol` won't be recursive, but the line for `Or` will include two recursive calls.

The key is not to match specific values in the sub-expressions of, say, the `Or` constructor.  That is, instead of trying to match `Or _ Empty` and all sorts of other `Or` cases, use a general `Or` match that binds the two alternatives to sub-expressions, and then work recursively on those sub-expressions.  For example, with a line like:

```
isEmpty (Or r1 r2) = ... isEmpty r1 ... isEmpty r2 ...
```

you will recursively have available the result of `isEmpty r1` which tells you if `r1` can match an empty input, and similarly the result of `isEmpty r2` which tells you if `r2` can match an empty input.

Every line should be the Haskell translation of a logical statement about the related constructor where `isEmpty r` is understood to mean that the regexp `r` can match the empty string.  So, when do we have `isEmpty (Or r1 r2)` (i.e., when does `Or r1 r2` match the empty string)?  Well, it's precisely when either `isEmpty r1` or `isEmpty r2`, and the definition is just the Haskell translation of this logic:

```
-- `Or` matches empty if either alternative matches empty
isEmpty (Or r1 r2) = isEmpty r1 || isEmpty r2
```